# Calling javascript from php script issue

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a php script which is editing records in mysql table. I have an issue in refreshing the page using javascript by passing the record number.

Pl check below are the few lines of my php script:

```
if ($mode == "edit")
{
$ids=$_POST[prs_rid];
$edt1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ECRDTL_edit WHERE id='$ids'");
$edt2=mysql_fetch_assoc($edt1);

echo "<script>var x=document.getElementById('prs_rid').value</script>";
    echo "<script> alert (x);</script>";
echo "<script>document.location.href='ecr-detail-edit.php?prs_mode=edit&prs_id='+x;</script>";
}
```

I have used alert to see if variable "x" is getting the record value or not, this works fine. But when i use the same in the next line, it is not showing the same record in the edit mode of my php.

But if I put the same line in address bar of a browser like this, it works fine:
     http://www.mydomain.com/ecr-detail-edit.php?prs_mode=edit&prs_id=27

Kindly check what could be the issue or is there any other way of refreshing the page passing the record number.

Comment: Side note: always be sure to sanitize user input. Currently you are basically plugging a POST variable into a MySQL query. You may as well post your database username and password to the public! Look at [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: check my answer, you had several errors, i have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative URL's don't work when assigned to `location.href`, it should be absolute or fully qualified.

In your case, absolute will do:

```
location.href = location.pathname + '?prs_mode=edit&prs_id=' + 
    encodeURIComponent(x)
```

The `location.pathname` gives the path (starting with `/`) up to the query separator (question mark).

I've also added `encodeURIComponent(x)` to make sure the value of `x` is properly escaped if necessary.

**Implementation**

```
echo "<script>location.href = location.pathname + '?prs_mode=edit&prs_id=' + encodeURIComponent(x);</script>";
```

Comment: jack your code above is not very clear to implement, could you please give a precise code to implement, that would help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `location.href` object which (as specified in [MDN window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)) belongs to the `window` object, not `document`.

So your last line of code should read like:

```
echo "<script>location.href='ecr-detail-edit.php?prs_mode=edit&prs_id='+x;</script>";
```

On another note, you will get better browser support using the script tags as `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: event this is not working. The effect is same with document.location.href or just location.href, so what else can i try.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.location.href='ecr-detail-edit.php?prs_mode=edit&prs_id='+x;
```

should be

```
location.href='ecr-detail-edit.php?prs_mode=edit&prs_id='+x;
```

and also you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape malicious data user may pass on to your script.

hence change

```
$ids = $_POST['prs_rid'];
```

to

```
$ids = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[prs_rid]);
```

you are missing script type, when you want to use javascript you need to tell to browser that the code being declared is of javascript, you need to change

```
<script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

you are missing single quotes in your POST data. add single quotes to the  following.

```
$ids = $_POST['prs_rid'];
```

one last thing is i would never output javascript with PHP. it is better you keep javascript and PHP different. for example your above code can be changed to.

```
<?php
if ($mode == "edit"):
    $ids  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prs_rid']);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ECRDTL_edit WHERE id='$ids'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById('prs_rid').value
    alert(x);
    location.href = 'ecr-detail-edit.php?prs_mode=edit&prs_id='+x;
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: NO event this does't work, effect is same. I have done changes as per your lines.

Comment: which browser you are using, if you are using google chrome then fire up developer console and check for javascript error if any. make sure you place javascript code after your html, otherwise it will give you HTML dom error.

Comment: not even this does't help, alert shows the correct record number, but still the problem is with the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that window.location needs an absolute, http:// URL. Use the following code:

```
window.location=window.location=location.protocol+'//'+location.host+location.pathname+"?get_variables_here";
```

Comment: the code given by you is not very clear. could you pl be more precise for me to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='ecr-detail-edit.php?prs_mode=edit&prs_id='+x;</script>";
```

Comment: This answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ the OP should try this.

Answer (score 0):

For this line to execute successfully, `var x=document.getElementById('prs_rid').value` in PHP, the html dom should be loaded first else it will give an error, which might be the issue here.